# NSAttributed string for UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to set custom spacing to my UISegmented Control. How can I define the `NSKernAttributeName` and `value` attribute to define custom spacing between the letters?

```
[myUIControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:myFont size:13]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This is how it is done for a `UIButton`

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:@(dinSpacing)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set character spacing for segment control as in the code below. You are doing it correctly, just add `NSKernAttributeName` as the key with a number value you are doing for the button, for example.

```
[self.aSegMentCntrl setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(5),NSKernAttributeName,[UIColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13],NSFontAttributeName ,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Your dictionary version

```
[self.aSegMentCntrl setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSKernAttributeName:@(5),NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was trying to add a range but I guess that isn't necessary

Comment: you are welcome .. :) .. no need to add range it take for whole string by default ..

Comment: I found that a negative value for kern (such as -4.0) works except for the last letter which is clipped. This is not a nice effect. Haven't you come across this?

Comment: @bio, no i used positive value to get expand effect, if u give negative value it shrinks, this is not a good effect